# Wrong number of arguments Ruby while instantiating a Subclass

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

I have 3 classes that hare related through inheritance (it's a course exercise)

I have a `Brand < Product < DBHandler` classes

They are in a subfolder of the project, and all of them use require to access each other:

```
├── class
│   ├── Brand.rb
│   ├── Category.rb
│   ├── DBHandler.rb
│   └── Product.rb
├── db
│   ├── catalogo_categorias.txt
│   ├── catalogo_marca.txt
│   ├── catalogo_producto.txt
│   └── inventario_final.txt
├── init.rb
└── README.md
```

### Clases

The Product file has in it:

```
require "#{Dir.pwd}/class/DBHandler"

class Product < DBHandler
  attr_reader :key, :final_price, :db
  attr_accessor :name, :unit, :brand, :category, :price

  def initialize(name, unit, brand, category, price)
    @name = name
    @unit = unit
    @brand = brand
    @category = category
    @price = price
    @final_price = set_final_price
    @db = DBHandler.new
    @key = set_key
  end

  def set_key
    @key = "#{@db.how_many+1}#{self.name[0..2].upcase}3BS"
  end

  def set_final_price
    @final_price = self.price * 1.19
  end

  def search_product(search_expresion)
    @db.db_search(search_expresion)
  end

  def alta_product
    @db.write(
      "#{key},#{name},#{unit},#{brand},#{category},#{price},#{final_price}\n"
    )
  end
end
```

and the Brand file has:

```
require "#{Dir.pwd}/class/Product"

class Brand < Product
  attr_reader :brand_key, :a_brands, :q_brands
  attr_accessor :brand

  def initialize(brand)
    # use super to use parent's attributes
    super(brand)
    @brand_key = set_brand_key
    @a_brands = get_file.read
                        .split("\n")
                        .map { |abrand| abrand.split(',') }
    @q_brands = @a_brands.count
  end

  def set_brand_key
    "#{@q_brands}#{self.brand[0..2].upcase}3BS"
  end

  def get_file
    File.open("#{Dir.pwd}/db/catalogo_marca.txt")
  end

  def alta_brand
    get_file.write("#{@brand_key},#{@brand}", mode: 'a')
  end
end
```

### Init file

All the files are called from the `init.rb` file in order to call some instance methods.

this is my `Init.rb` file first lines.

```
require './class/Product'
require './class/Brand'
require './class/DBHandler'
require './class/Category'
```

## The problem

when I want to create a new instance of `Brand` class, I have tried:

1. `brand = Brand.new(name, unit, brand, category, price)` and it returns `wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1) (ArgumentError)`
2. `brand = Brand.new(brand)` and it returns `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 5) (ArgumentError)`

I don't know what may I doing wrong.
I need to create a Brand instance with only `brand` argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
super(brand)
```

This is saying "call the parent constructor with `brand` as the only argument". The parent constructor is `Product#initialize`, which takes five arguments. So no matter how you call `Brand#initialize`, it's going to fail since it calls `Product#initialize` with the wrong number of arguments. You need to call `super` with all five.

But I challenge the frame. Subclassing is a very tight coupling, an ["is-a"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship. What you're claiming is that every brand *is a* product, and I fail to see how that's true. So rather than fixing the `super` call, you might reconsider your design and ask yourself if you really meant to make a subclass.

Comment: After defining `class DBHandler; end`, `Brand.instance_method(:initialize).super_method #=> #<UnboundMethod: Product#initialize(name, unit, brand, category, price)`, which is just what you said.

Comment: Hi!, I tough it was an error in the guide, It explicity says that Brand inherit from Product, and as you say, a subclass has a "is-a" relationship. 

when I delete the line `super(brand)` and now I can instantiate this new brand with the attributes I need.

Thank you for your advise! And I understood your point of subclassing and how are they related